# Visual Studio 2010 project, TFS and USB hard drive

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, usb

In my situation I use lots of different computers for doing my programming on.

Can I keep my Visual Studio 2010 projects on an external drive that I move between those machines while also using TFS?

I have had problems before with my workspace mappings if I move the project folder about on my computer and I guess my USB hard drive could end up having a different letters on each of the machines I use.

Any one got any tips or ticks for doing this?

(I know that I could use TFS to put my project on each computer however the Internet isn't always great from some of my locations so downloading the whole source isn't practical)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

This does not seem possible. 
TFS tracks workspaces, files and file states by computer name and workspace name. To be able to keep working on different physical computers, all those computers need to claim the same computer name, workspace name and also same folder structure on the same drive. Does not seem practical.

Suggestion 1 - You can make one computer as the master computer and keep the actual workspace on it. Take the solution offline. Copy your files to other computer(s). Do your stuff there. Come back to master computer and overwrite files in workspace. "Go Online" and hope to see VS be aware of changes. 
I haven't tried this, but it seems plausible

Suggestion 2 - Build your development environment on a virtual computer and carry it along with you.
First of all it will be slow and all host computers will need virtualization software installed.

Suggestion 3 - Keep your development computer close to TFS server and accessible via RDP.
Performance highly depends on network latency but this is my personal favorite.

and finally ....... nope ... that's all I got.

Comment: Latest news ... Brian Harry has a blog post about an upcoming feature in TFS 11 which could be a perfect solution for you.    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/08/02/version-control-model-enhancements-in-tfs-11.aspx

Answer (score 3):

1. use always the same drive name (e.g. S: you can always change it in computer management)
2. After connecting on new computer issue:

   tf workspaces /updateComputerName:MyOldComputerName /s:http://MyTFServer:8080

it will move workspace to your current computer

Comment: very useful - wish I'd known this when i was shuttling a USB drive back and forth between two laptops (one went in for service)

Answer (score 0):

this is very good idea, but I'm afraid that is not achievable. first - VS uses Registry keys to store some data, these keys have to be synced. secondly - VS has components that depends form your computer configuration, both computers have to be exactly the same. There are many other reasons

Comment: He isn't talking about having VS on the USB drive, just the projects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I can really give you a useful advice here since I don't use VS but I am using Eclipse and Dropbox and I don't understand why this wouldn't work. 
All you have to do is have an account in each computer with an identical login name and make sure that you designate the same workspace which resides inside your Dropbox.
If you want offline storage I guess it must be the same since (i.e.) Eclipse uses a hidden directory for setting workspace metadata (called .metadata) and it is contained within the user-defined workspace so if you copy your workspace make sure you copy the hidden directory.
Make a sample project in VS and let us know whether it worked for you or not :)

Answer (score 0):

to open it, The filename with .sln extension is needed...and if you try to open by going in to FILE >OPEN WEBSITE> most probably it will show empty..